# Download Legacy JVM Version 1.8 for MAC High Sierra

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jvm

I am trying to run Eclipse to develop Android apps. When I first opened Eclipse it provided a link to install legacy JVM from apple.com, after that was installed I am getting this error message
`Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.
Version: 1.8 or greater is required`

I installed the newer version (8u151) from java.com but that didn't help. I found the following link to download version 1.8 but that page has only the latest versions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Anyone figured out how to install Eclipse on Mac High Sierra?

Comment: What went wrong when installing with the newer version ?

Comment: It installed okay but Eclipse doesn't work with 8u151 or I don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get Eclipse work by installing the full 
Java SE Development Kit 8u151 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

java.com download or Apple's legacy JVM download did not work for Eclipse installation.

Answer (score 2):

The last time this kind of thing bit me I was inadvertently installing the run-time Java (which is what Apple usually provides a link to) on my server, not the full Java SDK (which has the compilers and stuff you need to do developmentn).

I usually hunt for the full Java SE Development Kit at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/.

Scroll down until you see **Download the Java SE Development Kit** http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it to work by installing Java SE Development Kit 8u151 without netbeans.